# Largest cluster sizes in sub-critical percolation

Tags: percolation

Consider a sub-critical site percolation problem on a square lattice with $N$ sites.

In the limit of large $N$, the (ensemble averaged) size $\mu$ of the largest cluster scales as ([see here](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.62.1660))
$$
\mu \sim s(p) \log N
$$
What is the dependence on $s(p)$ on the occupation probability $p$ in the limit of small $p$?